# what is the use of "<<=" operator?

Tags: serial

I recently read this piece of code and I dont know what is the use of "<<=" in the for loop:

```
for (mask = 0x01; mask>0; mask <<= 1) {
    if (data & mask){ // choose bit
```

This is the entire code:

```
//Created August 23 2006
//Heather Dewey-Hagborg
//http://www.arduino.cc

#include <ctype.h>

#define bit9600Delay 100  
#define halfBit9600Delay 500
#define bit4800Delay 188 
#define halfBit4800Delay 94 

byte rx = 6;
byte tx = 7;
byte SWval;

void setup() {
  pinMode(rx,INPUT);
  pinMode(tx,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(tx,HIGH);
  delay(2);
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH); //turn on debugging LED
  SWprint('h');  //debugging hello
  SWprint('i');
  SWprint(10); //carriage return
}

void SWprint(int data)
{
  byte mask;
  //startbit
  digitalWrite(tx,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bit9600Delay);
  for (mask = 0x01; mask>0; mask <<= 1) {
    if (data & mask){ // choose bit
     digitalWrite(tx,HIGH); // send 1
    }
    else{
     digitalWrite(tx,LOW); // send 0
    }
    delayMicroseconds(bit9600Delay);
  }
  //stop bit
  digitalWrite(tx, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(bit9600Delay);
}

int SWread()
{
  byte val = 0;
  while (digitalRead(rx));
  //wait for start bit
  if (digitalRead(rx) == LOW) {
    delayMicroseconds(halfBit9600Delay);
    for (int offset = 0; offset < 8; offset++) {
     delayMicroseconds(bit9600Delay);
     val |= digitalRead(rx) << offset;
    }
    //wait for stop bit + extra
    delayMicroseconds(bit9600Delay); 
    delayMicroseconds(bit9600Delay);
    return val;
  }
}

void loop()
{
    SWval = SWread(); 
    SWprint(toupper(SWval));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the other answers, the `<<=` operator shifts the byte to the left; however, the number '1'  after it specifies how far to shift it - so, `2 <<= 2` == 8.
Possibly clearer in binary:

`00000001 <<= 1` == `00000010`

`00000010 <<= 1` == `00000100`

`00000001 <<= 2` == `00000100`

Answer (score 7):

In simpler terms `mask <<= 1` is shorthand for `mask = mask << 1`

In general

```
variable operator= operand
```

is the augmented assignment operator which means

```
variable = variable operator operand
```

Answer (score 4):

`<<` is the left bit-shift operator. That means it takes the binary contents of a number and moves everything left by a certain number of binary places (1 place in this case). `<<=` simply combines the left bit-shift with an assignment, so it takes the current value of `mask`, shifts it left, and then stores the result back in `mask`.

In this situation, the `mask` variable starts with a value of `1`. The second time round the loop, it will be `10` (binary). Next time, it will be `100`, and so on. Since `mask` is a byte (which is 8 bits), it will go all the way up to `10000000` and then stop. After that, the 1 effectively falls-off the left and `mask` ends up with a value of 0.

The purpose of this in the code you provided is to test each individual bit within the `data` parameter. It basically goes through from least- to most-significant and checks if each bit is 1 or 0. It will then pull an output pin HIGH or LOW (respectively) to match. This allows it to send the contents of the variable digitally to some other device.

Doing low-level binary (aka bit-wise) operations like this is very common in microcontroller programming. If you're not familiar with it then I'd definitely recommend looking up some tutorials online. It opens up a huge range of new possibilities for your projects.